# JS Object Properties Definition shorthand

Tags: javascript, object, properties

So, i wondered, if there is a way to do something like this:

```js
var bar = function(){
    this = {
        name: 'baz',
        action: function(){
            alert('bark');
        }
    };
}
var foo = new bar();
console.log(foo.name);
foo.action();
```

Target: get a shorthand solution for code like `this.name = 'baz'; this.action = ...; this.etc =`, but, define it like a class, kinda, so i don't need declare default properties further.

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at here, defining defaults within the function that is the object's constructor is something you have to do if you want to use them as defaults. An object that is returned has the properties it's constructor gave it, so shorthand is always present. Are we discussing a certain object and it's constructor in particular or just an arbitrary extension?

Comment: @Dellirium it's not actually an `extension`, but just definition several properties in constructor function, without adding `this.` to every property. Like if i could just create a default anonymous object and copy it's properties to the object we creating. Hope i described my thoughts clearly :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Object.assign()` on `this` to add default values.

```js
var bar = function() {
  Object.assign(this, {
    name: 'baz',
    action: function() {
      alert('bark');
    }
  })
}
var foo = new bar();
console.log(foo.name);
foo.action();
```

Comment: Ye, this sounds correct. The only drawback is the old browsers compatibility. Still a working and semantically right way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modern browsers have [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
var bar = function () {
    Object.assign(this, {
        name: 'baz',
        action: function(){
            alert('bark');
        }
    });
};
var foo = new bar();
console.log(foo.name);
foo.action();
```

If you don't have `Object.assign` available, you can create your own `assign` (or `extend`, or `merge`...) function:

```
function assign(obj) {
    var objects;

    objects = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    objects.forEach(function (object) {
        var i;
        for (i in object) {
            if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, i)) {
                obj[i] = object[i];
            }
        }
    });

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is what i searched for. Unfortunately user above gave the answer earlier. Still, thanks for your contribution `=)`

Comment: @SLy_huh, if you look at the timestamps you'd see that he didn't, however I don't want to encourage you to change it because Nenad has a perfectly fine answer, and FGITW is a terrible reason to change a vote.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    Object.prototype.extend = function(obj) {
      for (var i in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
          this[i] = obj[i];
        }
      }
    };
    var bar = function() {
      this.extend({
        name: 'baz',
        action: function() {
          alert('bark');
        }
      });
    }
    var foo = new bar();
    console.log(foo.name);
    foo.action();
```

Comment: well, that's kind of a great solution. Will see, if someone can outpace it, else it will be the answer `' 3'`

Comment: Please don't encourage extending native prototypes, it's a recipe for disaster.